# google sites JS HTTP request

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I have a remote server that receives GET requests with parameter and returns a string.

I want to add a JS code in a google site page that will HTTP GET to that server and print the response string in a table, using the HTML box with:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Google sites does not approve it and rejects the function all together.
What other options do I have?

Comment: What's the reason Google sites rejects this type of code? Do they give some explanation as to why it's not allowed?
That might help suggesting an alternative solution.

Comment: WARNING: Your HTML contains some tags that are not permitted. These have been removed from your changes. That's all I get, just by posting the JS code with no HTML

Comment: Google sites disallows certain ways of using javascript. Could you provide a public link to site so we can have a look?